# Russification of errors on the web client of our system at the stage of user authorization

Tags: php, internationalization

Your help is very much needed.
P.S.: Unfortunately, I'm not a developer and I'm not strong in php
There are 4 files and code related to this question:

1. cloud\app\app.cpp

```
private function __construct()
  {
    $this->time_start = self::timeMeasure();

    $parsed_url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $this->_baseUrl = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'].'/' : '';
    
    $this->_path2root = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->_path2root = realpath($this->_path2root);
    $this->_path2model = $this->_path2root.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'app'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'models'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->_path2lib = $this->_path2root.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'app'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'libs'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lang']))
    {
      $locale_file = $this->_path2root.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'i18n'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_REQUEST['lang'].'.php';
      if(is_file($locale_file))
      {
        $this->locale = require $locale_file;
      }
    }
  }

public function t($message)
  {
    if(!isset($this->locale)) return $message;
    if(isset($this->locale[$message])) return $this->locale[$message];
    return $message;
  }
```

2. cloud\app\libs\error.php

```
static private function _Msg($id) 
  {
    $user='';
    $msgs = array(
    self::UserAuthErr  => array('msg' => App::get()->t('User "%s" from ip "%s" authentication error: %u.'),
                                    'user' => $user,
                                    'category' => ErrorCategory::User,
                                    'level' => ErrorLevel::Alert,
                                    'module' => ErrorModule::Auth,
                                    'error' => ErrorCode::Authentification,
                                    'snumber' => 0),
    );
    if(isset($msgs[$id]))
        {
          $ar = $msgs[$id];
          $ar['user'] = 'SYSTEM';
          $ar['user_id'] = 0;
          if(isset($_SESSION['USER_NAME'])) $ar['user'] = $_SESSION['USER_NAME'];
          if(isset($_SESSION['USER_UID'])) $ar['user_id'] = $_SESSION['USER_UID'];
          return $ar;
        }
    return array();
  }
```

3. cloud\ajax\i18n.php

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/app.php';
App::get()->includeLibs();
if(!App::get()->loadConfig('/config/main.cfg'))
{
  $aaData = array('error' => 'Fatal error: Config not found');
  echo Utils::safe_json_encode($aaData);
  exit;
}
```

4. cloud\i18n\ru.php

```
<?
  return array(
    'User "%s" from ip "%s" authentication error: %u.' => 'Ошибка аутентификации пользователя "%s" с ip "%s". Код ошибки: %u.',
  );
```

For some reason, the array from the ru.php file is not returned. There is a suspicion that the t() function, which should refer to the ru.php file, does not see it. Can you tell me where to dig or what this problem is connected with?

Comment: Whether `if(is_file($locale_file))` in the constructor is actually true or not, should be easy enough to verify.